# Strange yield syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, yield, taskjs

I just took a look at Dave Herman's very interesting [task.js](https://github.com/dherman/taskjs/blob/master/README.md). In his example he has this line:

```
var [foo, bar] = yield join(read("foo.json"),
                                read("bar.json")).timeout(1000);
```

I'm familiar with generators but I don't understand how the yield expression evaluates to something that can be assigned to [foo, bar]. I actually wouldn't have expected the expression to be assignable to anything since it is basically the same thing as return.

The yield syntax for JS still seems a bit underdocumented and I couldn't find info about this.

So to clarify my question: what ends up being assigned to foo and bar?

Comment: BTW I wanted to add a "taskjs" keyword but it seems I don't have enough reputation for this.

Comment: Please remember to ask a question :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the relevant paragraph is a little below in https://developer.mozilla.org/En/New_in_JavaScript_1.7:

> Once a generator has been started by calling its `next()` method, you
>   can use `send()`, passing a specific value that will be treated as the
>   result of the last `yield`. The generator will then return the operand
>   of the subsequent `yield`.

I think that this is only relevant if the generator is used by calling its methods directly, not when looping over its values - a loop will always call `next()` on the generator and never `send()`.

In a way, generator execution is similar to cooperative multitasking. The generator executes until the `yield` statement is found. It returns control to whoever called `next()` or `send()` on the generator. The caller then continues executing, until the next `next()` or `send()` call is performed - now the generator is executing again. Each time values can be passed back and forth.

Here a simple example:

```
function gen()
{
  var [foo, bar] = yield 1;
  console.log("Generator got: " + foo + ", " + bar);
}

// This creates a generator but doesn't run it yet
var g = gen();

// Starts generator execution until a yield statement returns a value
var result = g.next()
console.log("Received from generator: " + result);

// Continue generator execution with [2, 3] being the return value
// of the yield statement. This will throw StopIteration because the
// iterator doesn't have any more yield statements.
g.send([2, 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/New_in_JavaScript_1.7

> The function containing the yield keyword is a generator. When you call it, its formal parameters are bound to actual arguments, but its body isn't actually evaluated. Instead, a generator-iterator is returned. Each call to the generator-iterator's next() method performs another pass through the iterative algorithm. Each step's value is the value specified by the yield keyword. Think of yield as the generator-iterator version of return, indicating the boundary between each iteration of the algorithm. Each time you call next(), the generator code resumes from the statement following the yield.

Comment: I understand all that by I don't understand why the yield statement doesn't occur in a loop (which I would expect to get iterator-style semantics) and why there is a direct assignment performed using whatever the yield evaluates to. As you say, it's like a return, so this seems to me like saying `var something = return something_else;`. I've never seen that usage and I'm not sure what it would mean.